# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASWebAuthenticationSession"

Tags: ios, cocoapods, cpu-architecture, onesignal, visual-studio-app-center

I am using OneSignal for remote notifications. And using appCenter pod for analytics and crashes.
But it seems I'm not able to link OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension(x86_64).
it gives the following warning:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_ASWebAuthenticationSession", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in AppCenterDistribute(MSACDistribute.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It was previously working fine. It seems it got messed up when I updated the pods.
Notes:

-pod 'OneSignal', '>= 3.0.0'

- pod 'AppCenter'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes'
  pod 'AppCenter/Distribute'
- using Xcode 12
- AppCenter/Analytics (3.1.1):

  - AppCenter/Core
  - AppCenter/Core (3.1.1)
  - AppCenter/Crashes (3.1.1):

    - AppCenter/Core
  - AppCenter/Distribute (3.1.1):

    - AppCenter/Core

Please let me know how to solve it. I have deintegrated and re-installed the pods several times.

Comment: Could you please clarify the version of App Center SDK and which platform do you use? Recently was the release of App Center SDK with improvements: [Apple](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/releases/tag/4.1.1) and 
[DotNet](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/4.2.0).

Does updating to the latest version solve your problem?

Comment: As a workaround, you can add the `AuthenticationServices` dependency manually.

Comment: @Anastasia I used version 1.2.0. It seems without specifying version it was conflicting with Alamofire version 4.9.1

Comment: after specifying the version by hit and trial, it worked. But there must be a better way. Also, it would be very helpful If I knew the reason how it occured

Comment: Have solved this issue??? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: As a workaround, you can add the AuthenticationServices dependency manually.